# How to merge QPainterPaths

Tags: qt, qt4

I need to "merge" two `QPainterPath` together. The problem is that they always seems to be two different paths.

What I need is that the merge really become the sames as if a single one ( from a complex polygon or a complex bunch of lines) had been constructed, without any inner line artifacts or subpath from the fact that they were two distinct paths previously. It seems a pretty simple and normal task but I can't figure how to do it.

Comment: It is not completely clear what "seems to be two different paths" means. Maybe it's the same as I had. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the `united(QPainterPath)` method (QPainterPath class) is the one you are looking for, if you did not try it yet. Or maybe `subtracted(QPainterPath)`, or `intersected(QPainterPath)`, depending on what you try to achieve.

Could you please give us more details about what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

It might help to first merge the paths using the overloaded `+` operator and then call `simplified()` on it. [QPainterPath reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QPainterPath.html)

At least that solved the problem for me when I had two paths of two squares that had one edge in common and without a call to `simplified()` it would still be two squares but with it would be one rectangle as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with two paths p1 and p2, each containing a single subpath, then:

```
joined = p1.toSubpathPolygons()[0] + p2.toSubpathPolygons()[0]
p3 = QPainterPath()
p3.addPolygon(joined)
```

You can also change the direction that each path is joined by using path.toReversed().
(sorry, this is python syntax but should be nearly the same for C++)

Comment: It seems like p3 = p1 + p2 (also python syntax) is having the same effect (eg. for p1 and p2 being two rectangle being close together it is identical).